# Dataframe pandas To csv

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, sqlite3

Tengo una tabla en SQLITE3 con una sola columna PALABRAS con distintas palabras, y quiero que el usuario genere un archivo .csv con esas palabras delimitadas por comas. Para ello he usado el siguiente código, primero selecciono todas las palabras de la tabla con una consulta, las paso a un dataframe y desde del dataframe utilizo la función que ofrece pandas .to_csv, el código es el siguiente:

```
cursor = self.db_conection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
df.columns = ['palabras']
# DF TO CSV
df.to_csv('nombre_archivo.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Bien pues lo hace todo bien pero el archivo que me genera tiene esta apariencia:

[image: Captura del archivo producido]

Si lo abro con Excel tiene la misma apariencia, sin embargo en la descripción pone archivo de valores separado por comas, pero yo no veo las comas por ningún sitio.

Comment: La parte "separado por comas" de CSV se refiere a cómo separa una columna de otra. En este formato cada fila es una línea, y si en la misma fila hay varias columnas, éstas aparecen separadas por comas. En tu caso, al haber una sola columna, no hay comas. El resultado es correcto. No está claro si lo que quieres es que haya una coma al final de cada línea, o que todas las palabras estén en una sola línea, separadas por comas

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había fijado en ese detalle. Es decir un archivo CSV delimitado por comas tiene esa estructura y ya está no? Si hay una única columna pues no saldrán comas.

Comment: @AlfredoLopezRodes exacto. Prueba quitando la parte `df.columns = ['palabras']` y notarás la diferencia.